# how to add condition to a function

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

```
<ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, // any parent
    'caption' => $post->post_excerpt

    ) ; 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
         //if ( 'caption' == 'Ceahlau') {
            echo '<li>';
                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                            echo '<p>';
                            echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
                            echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $attachment->post_excerpt );
                            echo '</p></li>';
       // }
    }
}

    endwhile; endif;?>
</u>
```

I want to add the if condition that is commented but I don't know how... can you help me please. In this form the function is working but if i uncomment the condition it does not post anything...

Comment: Is the caption value a string ('Ceahlau'0

Comment: if so, set a variable $caption to the string value before the if condition

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $args['caption'] == 'Ceahlau')
```